# Batch check reachable machines

Tags: batch-file, ping, errorlevel

I have used several scripts posted in this forum unsuccesfully.
Script is as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (computersTest.txt) do (
        ping -n 1 %%i | find "TTL" >nul 2>nul
    Echo %errorlevel%
)
```

Errorlevel is always 0 no matter if host is reachable or not. If I remove the >nul to see the output I get the following

```
Reply from 10.6.4.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
0
0
Reply from 10.6.5.58: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=126
0
```

Where the second host in the list is not reachable but errolevel is 0

If I execute in the command prompt

```
ping -n 1 XXXXXXXXX | find "TTL" >NUL 2>NUL
```

`echo %errorlevel%`

gives 1

I don't know what I am doing wrong

TIA
Ramon

Answer (score 2):

Batch lines or blocks of lines (lines enclosed in parenthesis) are first parsed and then executed. During the parse phase, all read operations on variables are removed from code, replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the line/block. So, if a variable is changed inside a line/block, this new value can not be retrieved from inside the same line/block, as there is not a read operation to retrieve the new value.

You can solve it using delayed expansion and changing (where needed) the syntax from `%var%` into `!var!`, to indicate to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the command executes

In your case

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in (computersTest.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 %%i | find "TTL=" >nul 2>nul
    Echo %%i - !errorlevel!
)
```

*note*: The correct test in ipv4 for response is to search for `TTL=`, as you can have a false positive in case of a TTL expired error.

But in the case of checking the `errorlevel` variable, there are more alternatives (if they are applicable).

You can use the native `if errorlevel n` where the condition will be evaluated to true for any errorlevel equal or greater than `n`

```dos
@echo off
for /f %%i in (computersTest.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 %%i | find "TTL=" >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo %%i offline ) else ( echo %%i online )
)
```

Or you can use conditional execution. The operators `&&` and `||` will allow to include what to execute depending on the errorlevel (not set or set) from previous command

```dos
@echo off
for /f %%i in (computersTest.txt) do (
    ( ping -n 1 %%i | find "TTL=" >nul 2>nul ) && echo %%i online || echo %%i offline
)
```